# Try to transform bcrypt.hash callback into promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, callback, bcrypt

In order to practice in JS, I'm trying to write the same code using a callback and a promise.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
const myPlaintextPassword = 'secret';
```

1. Callback version

```
function hashPassword(password, callback) {
    bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err); // EDIT
        }
        return callback(null, hash); // EDIT
    });
}

hashPassword(myPlaintextPassword, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    return console.log(hash);
})
```

2. Promise version

```
async function hashPassword(password) {
    return await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);
}

hashPassword(myPlaintextPassword)
    .then(res => console.log("result :", res))
    .catch(err => console.log("error :", err));
```

Question : are these snippets "identical" (under the hood) ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean with identical. In a strict sense, of course not. Also, your callback version should always have a `return` in the `if (err)` case. In the first function, it falls through into the success callback.

Comment: Can we use one or the other indifferently ? Even for the "error" case ?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? You cannot use them indifferently, because the second can be used with the typical promise constructs, while the first cannot. The second involves messages on the Promise Job Queue, while the first does not (apart from what the API itself may do internally).... etc